# android Setting Multiple Alarms

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

First of all , i'd read many many answers about this problem ,
I want to set 5 alarms working but with different times , the problem is the last one overrides the others so i see the last one only ,
i tried to change the request code of the PendingIntent to make it unique but the problems still as it is : 
i'd rewritten the code many times really but the same result,
i tried to make one method for all the alarms and changing the request code in but no use , also i tried to make different methods for every alarm with unique request codes  but still the last alarm overrides the others, 
here is my code for two methods as an example : 

Note : 
variables that i have 
fajrMillis,dhuhrMillis : 
are the milliseconds which are converted to a calendar to set the time in 
fajrMessage,dhuhrMessage : the string messages to be sent to the receiver class to the notification in it 
Calling the two methods :

```css
setFajrAlarm(fajrMillis, 1, fajrMessage);
setDhuhrAlarm(dhuhrMillis, 2, dhuhrMessage);
```

```css
public void setFajrAlarm(long millis, int id, String message) {
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTimeInMillis(millis);
  PrayersReceiver.notificationId = id;// 1
  PrayersReceiver.notificationMessage = message;// "حان الآن موعد صلاة الفجر"
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrayersReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    c.getTimeInMillis(),30000, pendingIntent);

 }

 public void setDhuhrAlarm(long millis, int id, String message) {
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTimeInMillis(millis);
  PrayersReceiver.notificationId = id;// 1
  PrayersReceiver.notificationMessage = message;// "حان الآن موعد صلاة الظهر
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrayersReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    c.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
 
 }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Receiver Class

```css
package com.prayers;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PrayersReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 public static String notificationMessage = "";
 public static int notificationId ;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(context, "Time For Prayer", 3000).show();

  // -----------------
  // --------------Notification Part---------------------------
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("حان الآن موعد الصلاة")
    .setContentText(notificationMessage);

  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
 }

}
```

Thanks in advance , hope to get the answers soon

Answer (score 0):

I knew the answer so if anyone faces this problem to get the solution : 
i was setting the variables values  in the receiver class so the last method call overrides the previous calls :

```css
PrayersReceiver.notificationId = id;
PrayersReceiver.notificationMessage = message;
```

the problem was in these two lines in the method body : 
so it got solved by  :

```css
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrayersReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("notificationId", id);
intent.putExtra("notificationMessage", message);
```

and in the receiver class get the two values :

```css
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle == null) {
    Log.i("PrayersReceiver", "bundle is null");
 return;
  }

notificationId = bundle.getInt("notificationId");
notificationMessage = bundle.getString("notificationMessage");
```